# how to populate the two database tables in one to many relation in Jmeter

Tags: database, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I need to populate two tables in a one to many relation such a way that the first table's primary key is the foreign key for the second table.
The situation is when I populate the first table with 1st entry, It should create 3 entries in second table with taking first table primary key as the foreign key for the second table.

How can i achieve the same.
[jmeter config for first table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfJka.png)
So here entity_id is the primary key for this table and it is obtained from the counter. and all the other values are read from the csv file

[jmeter config for 2nd table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMcOm.png)
This is the second table and parent_id should be the foreign key for this table.
one entry 1st table should create multiple entries in the second table

I tried to add the forEachController but it did not work for me.

in simple code I need to implement this code in the Jmeter
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

```
INSERT INTO "table_1" VALUES (primary_key(Table1_id),2,24,5);
    int num = rand.nextInt(5);
    for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
        INSERT INTO "table_2" VALUES (id,forign_key(Table1_id),34,5);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2nd JDBC Request sampler under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), the incremented number can be referred using  [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) function like:

```
${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)}
```

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)